# mysql pivot table image list (vertical to horizontal data)

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have been searching for hours but with my limited MySQL knowledge I just can't figure out an answer.

I want to transform this table:

```
listingsdb_id listingsimages_file_name
-----------  ------------  
93            name-a.jpg    
93            name-b.jpg
94            name-c.jpg
95            name-d.jpg
95            name-e.jpg
95            name-f.jpg
95            name-g.jpg
```

Into this:

```
listingsdb_id Image1        Image2        Image3        Image4,      Image5,Image6...
-----------  ------------   ------------  ------------  ------------
93            name-a.jpg    name-b.jpg    
94            name-c.jpg    
95            name-d.jpg    name-e.jpg    name-f.jpg    name-g.jpg
```

Using MySQL